# PyCups - How to get PPM for a Printer?

Tags: python-2.7, cups

I need to know how many page per minute can print a cups printer.
I use python cups (pycups). I'm on Linux and I use python 2.7

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not every printer will have that attribute listed in its Postscript Printer Description (PPD) file.

However, if it is there, it is accessible as:

```
import cups
conn = cups.Connection()
printername = conn.getPrinters().keys()[2] # take a valid printer name
conn.getPrinterAttributes(printername, requested_attributes=["pages-per-minute"])
# alternative: conn.getPrinterAttributes(printername)['pages-per-minute']
```

CUPS shows the value it found for the `Throughput` attribute in the PPD file.